# Yii and Git Repos

Tags: php, git, yii

I'm learning both Yii and Git at the same time, and am finding issues with my commits. I'm using BitBucket if that matters any.

Basically, if I create a project and commit to the repo, when I then try to pull that repo onto another machine, I start with a whole bunch of Yii runtime configuration errors.

I've found a way around it, but it seems messy. If I load an older commit of the repo from just after the project was added and delete the project manually then re-add it through the yii tools (yiic) I can overwrite it then with the updates from the most recent commit to get everything back.

This seems messy and like it's asking for trouble. Is there something I'm doing wrong here with Yii?

**Edit**
Below is the exact error message as it appears:

```
CException

Application runtime path "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/projects/trackstar/protected/runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yii-sandbox/framework/base/CApplication.php(289)

277             return $this->_runtimePath;
278         }
279     }
280 
281     /**
282      * Sets the directory that stores runtime files.
283      * @param string $path the directory that stores runtime files.
284      * @throws CException if the directory does not exist or is not writable
285      */
286     public function setRuntimePath($path)
287     {
288         if(($runtimePath=realpath($path))===false || !is_dir($runtimePath) || !is_writable($runtimePath))
289             throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Application runtime path "{path}" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.',
290                 array('{path}'=>$path)));
291         $this->_runtimePath=$runtimePath;
292     }
293 
294     /**
295      * Returns the root directory that holds all third-party extensions.
296      * @return string the directory that contains all extensions. Defaults to the 'extensions' directory under 'protected'.
297      */
298     public function getExtensionPath()
299     {
300         return Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext');
301     }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with more details on these errors? First guess. It happens, because you added into your repository directory with private temporary files

Comment: added code. I'm not sure what you mean by private temp files - again new to yii and .git - is there a particular directory i should be ignoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added your `main.php` configuration file to the git repository. That file contains per-host configuration settings that will likely not be valid if the file is transferred to another machine, as you are finding out.

The solution is to not include the live configuration file in the repository. Instead, include a reference configuration file (that won't be loaded by Yii) and copy its contents to a new `main.php` when you deploy. Here's what you need to do as the first step:

```
git mv main.php main.reference.php
git commit -m "renamed configuration file"
```

After this you also need to add the name `/protected/config/main.php` to the list of the files that git ignores, so that it won't bother you about unversioned files in your deployment directory. To do this, create a file named `.gitignore` in the root directory of your checkout and add the line

```
protected/config/main.php
```

Comment: 1 more thing to add - even after pull you'll need to setup proper rights for runtime folder and assets.

Comment: thanks - that's worked. The paths were slightly different from one machine to another. I've used this process as well for managing the live version, as the `framework` and `requirements` directories aren't in the `public_html` folders. It requires a bit of juggling to setup, but once there it's much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

try to use gitignore to put the user dependent files there so that these files will not be overridden while pulling and pushing