# Why does cloning a repo break my yii2 app?

Tags: git, bitbucket, yii2

I have a Yii framework app and it breaks when I clone it.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766513/yii-and-git-repos) that, in Yii, the `main.php` file had to be excluded, but what am I supposed to ignore with Yii2?
(Sorry, I'm still new to frameworks...)

Comment: define "breaks"... Also install yii2 from the official repo and search for .gitingore files to see what is ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you clone your app you will need to check and do a few things. Some of them will depend on the template you use:

- Run `composer install` to install dependencies
- If you're using the advanced template you should run `./init`
- In advanced template running the above  `./init` will create a main-local configuration file with a bogus `db`component. You will need to manually set the password here (or remove it if your config is versioned in main.php).
- Depending on your application you might need to run various `db migrations` via `./yii migrate`. Such is the case if you're using the `DbManager` of the RBAC system, or any migrations created within your app

In regards to testing (using codeception) you will have to do the following:

- Build codeception using : `codecept build -c tests/codeception.yml` for basic template or `codecept build -c tests/codeception/<suite>/codeception.yml` for advanced template, where `<suite>`is the suit you will be running (ex: common, console, frontend,etc..)
- Depending on your application you may also need to run migrations on the test environment with `tests/codeception/bin/yii migrate`

**Replace yii with yii.bat for windows**

PS: you definitely do not want to ignore your main.php/web.php files. This wasn't even good practice in Yii1.

Comment: I will try this, I just installed ubuntu on my laptop and I will give it a try and give some feedback :)

Comment: works, but the ./init won't work because there is no init file :P

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer to better differentiate between basic and advanced template.